# Dynamic js answers depending on input from user

Tags: javascript

I want to make a form whith questions and when a user answers in an input box there should be an immidiate answere under that box. Like Question: 
What car do you drive? Me: Ford

Dynamic response: So you drive a Ford!
Well what kind of Ford?

"Another input box to answer into for user"

This should all be done with javascript, no jQuery. I need some guidlines where to start.

Answer (score 2):

html

```
<div id='questions'></div>​
```

and javascript

```
var _$ = function(id) {
    return document.getElementById(id);
};

var handle = function(e, div, num, q) {
    num = num || 0;

    var n_div = document.createElement('div');
    n_div.innerHTML = q[num].replace(/\$\{ans\}/g, e.value);
    console.log(e.value)
    div.appendChild(n_div);

    if (num + 1 < q.length) {
        var i = document.createElement('input');
        i.type = 'text';
        i.onblur = function() {
            handle(i, div, num + 1, q);
        };

        div.appendChild(i);
    }
};

var question = [
    'What car do you drive?',
    'So you drive a ${ans}, what kind?',
    'I like the ${ans} kind, where do you drive it?',
    'Its nice to drive at ${ans}'
], div;

div = _$('questions');

var n_div = document.createElement('div');
n_div.innerHTML = question[0];
div.appendChild(n_div);

var i = document.createElement('input');
i.type = 'text';
i.onblur = function() {
    handle(i, div, 1, question);
};                               
div.appendChild(i);
```

here you go, a working [example](http://jsfiddle.net/epoch/2Bh67/)

Comment: Thanks. How would this look without innerhtml? Also I tried to get the keypressed and write that out as the user inputs text. The thing is I dont know how to get the other words in there, Like: So you drive a "input word". Is there a way to use this method? Because then we can get the input outwritten at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using different events available for the input test box.
for example, you can use `onchange` or `onblur` events for the text box and write the appropriate logic in those events. So that will be executed dynamically.
See this [reference](http://www.w3schools.com/html5/tag_input.asp)

Comment: dont reference w3scools... ever. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/120025/will-i-be-downvoted-for-giving-a-w3schools-link, also http://w3fools.com/

Answer (score 0):

Use JQuery which lets you handle events easliy. The specific one you might want is change: http://api.jquery.com/change/

However, judging from the fact that you have to ask where to start I would recommend that you read some tutorials on the matter. See for example: http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials:Getting_Started_with_jQuery

Comment: He specifically said no jQuery, yet your answer points to jQuery?